# A custom user alias for favourited questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, bookmarks

Sometimes, users ask questions with non descriptive titles but the body of the question describes his/her question clearly and other users solved the problem.

Later on, when I search in my favourite questions list I take time to look at the
corresponding question because the title is not that clear, for example (the title is: object reference is null).

My suggestion is that when user marks a question as a favourite, show a floating text-box to enter his/her alias. When a user opens his favourites, the list will show both the original titles and aliased titles, if they exist.

Comment: Why not edit or suggest an edit for the title if the title is vague?

Comment: You have no idea how painful it was for me to not add a "u" to favorited in the title. Then I noticed that you have them all throughout the question body. YAY!

Comment: Declining this as it's worded...editing is absolutely the way to go here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a user who is gaining experience on Stack Overflow, at just over 1200 reputation, you've spent enough time on Stack Overflow now to know the difference between a good title and a bad one.

In fact, you've actually experienced the pain of not being able to tell what a question is about, simply because of a poorly written title. This experience will help make you a great editor!

One of the features that makes Stack Overflow really awesome is the editing capabilities. If something isn't clear, and you know how to make it clear, then you can suggest an edit. While you're at it, you should fix other problems with the post that you see, like spelling, grammar, and code formatting, as this will make it more likely that your edit will be approved.

Until you hit 2000 reputation, any suggested edit you make that is approved will yield you an additional 2 reputation. Most importantly, there's no need to implement a new feature for managing favorites, since you can not only fix the title for yourself but for all future visitors as well! :)  Good luck!

Comment: You're completely correct, thank you.